# DLL C++ import functions to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dllimport

How do I access the functions of a C++ DLL in Delphi

```
 #define CCONV _stdcall 
  typedef struct{ 
    unsigned long BaudRate; 
    unsigned char PortNumber; 
    ..... 
  }SSP_COMMAND;

NOMANGLE int CCONV OpenSSPComPort (SSP_COMMAND * cmd);
```

In documentation:
**OpenSSPComPort**

Parameters:  **Pointer** to SSP_COMMAND structure

Returns:     WORD 0 for fail, 1 for success

I suspect I am wrong about this **Pointer**.

In Delphi I am attempting this:

```
type
  SSP_COMMAND=class
   BaudRate:integer;
   PortNumber:integer;
end;

type
 TOpenSSPComPort = function (sspc:SSP_COMMAND):Integer;stdcall;

    var nv11 : THandle;
    OpenSSPComPort:TOpenSSPComPort;

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin

    if nv11 = 0 then
    begin
      nv11 := LoadLibrary(pchar('ITLSSPProc.dll'));
      @OpenSSPComPort:=GetProcAddress(nv11, 'OpenSSPComPort');

      ss_cmd := SSP_COMMAND.create;

    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ss_cmd.BaudRate := 9600;
    ss_cmd.PortNumber :=8;

   If OpenSSPComPort(ss_cmd)=0 Then
   Memo1.lines.add('Error OpenSSPComPort')
   else
   Memo1.lines.add('OpenSSPComPort - OK');

  end;
```

So result is :  COM0   - Can't open this port
but I sent **8**
this means then SSP_COMMAND was sent incorrectly

Comment: Does it work if you change "stdcall" with "cdecl"?

Comment: How is `CCONV` defined - really `stdcall`? How is `SSP_COMMAND` defined - is it really a `class`? Why haven't you [linked to any source](https://github.com/muccc/fnordload/blob/master/vendor/NV9USB/esspdeveloperkit/ITLSSPProcCode/SSPComs.cpp)? Please use formatting so we can distinguish what's a documentation citation and where it ends. Consider using more punctuation and fewer line breaks.

Comment: I found in sourses of DLL  = #define CCONV _stdcall   and  for SSP_COMMAND   typedef struct{
 unsigned long BaudRate;
 unsigned char PortNumber;
.....
}SSP_COMMAND;

Comment: Next time edit your post instead of packing code unformatted into a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C definition from the link you provided, you would need to change the following:

```
type
  SSP_FULL_KEY = packed record
    FixedKey : UINT64;
    EncryptKey : UINT64;
end;  

type
  SSP_COMMAND=packed record
    key : SSP_FULL_KEY;
    BaudRate:integer;
    PortNumber:integer;
    SSPAddress : byte;
    RetryLevel : byte; 
    EncryptionStatus : byte;
    CommandDataLength : byte;
    CommandData : Array[0..254] of byte;
    ResponseStatus : byte;
    ResponseDataLength : byte;
    ResponseData : Array[0..254] of byte;
  end;
  PSSP_COMMAND = ^SSP_COMMAND;

type
  TOpenSSPComPort = function (sspc:PSSP_COMMAND):Integer;stdcall;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ss_cmd : SSP_COMMAND; 
begin 
  FillChar(ss_cmd, sizeof(ss_cmd), 0);
  ss_cmd.BaudRate := 9600;
  ss_cmd.PortNumber :=8;

  If OpenSSPComPort(@ss_cmd)=0 Then
    Memo1.lines.add('Error OpenSSPComPort')
  else
    Memo1.lines.add('OpenSSPComPort - OK');
end;
```

Comment: Until it worked out... (mrbat) Thanks for the answer, everything is quite logical.
For those who asked for more information. Here is the source of the library and an example of connection in C
 https://github.com/muccc/fnordload/tree/3fa0c6ccd2cdbe937e077d97b9b399493829dfc7/vendor/NV9USB/esspdeveloperkit

Comment: Why should the record be packed?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I actually always use packed records when it comes to interaction with dlls. Afaik the default VS alignment is 1 anyway (correct me if I'm wrong...)

Comment: Default is aligned rather than packed, so yes you are wrong.

Comment: @mrabat Have a look in one of your project's settings and you'll see that "_Record field alignment_" is most likely set to `8`, not `1`.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess for this structure it doesn't make any difference though - the record defined in the comman record is aligned anyway so one can omit it anyway. Nevertheless that would be the first dll definition that would use some alignment differen than packed. In addition I assumed a packed record since the python bindings use pack on a few occassion.

Comment: This is right answer realy. My mistake was not the correct sequence of the structure SSP_COMMAND

Answer (score -2):

This special library works like this(may be useful to someone)
I don't know why this  works for Windows XP and works for Windows 10 64bit but not works on another computer with fisical device and Windows 10 64bit

```
type
 SSP_COMMAND = class
   BaudRate:integer;
   PortNumber:byte;
   //... have more properties
end;

PSSP_COMMAND=^SSP_COMMAND;

TOpenSSPComPort=  function (sspc:PSSP_COMMAND):Integer;stdcall;


var
  Form1: TForm1;
  nv11 : THandle;
  OpenSSPComPort:TOpenSSPComPort;
  ss_cmd:PSSP_COMMAND;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject)
begin

   nv11 := LoadLibrary(pchar('ITLSSPProc.dll'));
   @OpenSSPComPort:=GetProcAddress(nv11, 'OpenSSPComPort');

 // only here, when creating form or class
 New(ss_cmd);   
 ss_cmd^ := SSP_COMMAND.create;


end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin



 ss_cmd.BaudRate := 9600;
 ss_cmd.PortNumber :=3;

   if OpenSSPComPort(ss_cmd)=0 Then
       Memo1.lines.add('Error OpenSSPComPort');
   else
       Memo1.lines.add('OpenSSPComPort - OK');

end;
```

If I change
**SSP_COMMAND = class**
to
**SSP_COMMAND = record**
It not works

The pointer to the SSP_COMMAND structure becomes invalid and the function does not work at all

I try

```
   type
   SSP_COMMAND = record
   ...
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject)
begin       
   New(ss_cmd); // only here
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

    
 
 ss_cmd^.BaudRate := 9600;
 ss_cmd^.PortNumber :=3;

   if OpenSSPComPort(ss_cmd)=0 Then
       Memo1.lines.add('Error OpenSSPComPort');
   else
       Memo1.lines.add('OpenSSPComPort - OK');

end;
```

and it doesn't work like that

Comment: `typedef struct` is not a `class`, it's a `record` - I'm highly surprised this doesn't crash!

Comment: This code works on WindowsXP 32bit , on Windows 10 64 bit - no .... Access Violation at ardess... in DLL...

Comment: Wrong-way drivers argue the same way: it "works" for them. The code can act differently as per compiler and its version, producing different binaries.